# React-Router-Dom: Difference between using component inside route synax vs. using /* component={componentName} */ syntax?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am new to React and I have seen two different syntaxes for routing using react-router-dom, as illustrated below with Example1 and Example2.  Welcome is just a standard react component.

Example1:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/"><Welcome /></Route>
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Example2:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Welcome} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Is there any difference between the two syntaxes?  As of 2021 is there a preference?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/component) already answers this for you:

> When you use `component` (instead of `render` or `children`) the router uses `React.createElement` to create a new React element from the given component. **That means if you provide an inline function to the component prop, you would create a new component every render. This results in the existing component unmounting and the new component mounting instead of just updating the existing component**. When using an inline function for inline rendering, use the `render` or the `children` prop.

Comment: Okay, if Im understanding correctly seems like using Render or Children is better practice than using component.  Seems bizarre that so many tutorials would use component!

Comment: It usually isn't that big of a deal for "simple" routes. The router only re-renders when the location changes, which usually involves switching routes/pages and therefore isn't affected by the re-render. But if you have a complex route, e.g. one for `/project/{project}/jobs/{job}`, then switching from job 1 to job 2 would re-render the whole component, even if you only expected to switch a job route in a sub-router in your component.